# oauth and userid

Tags: oauth, userid

i am very confused, once i get the access token from google to access user contacts,

how do I associate that user with that token again in the future?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got confused between openid, oauth, and hybrid openid+oauth.
what i really want is hybrid openid+oauth, where i have the openid as key and access token is linked to it.

thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist that access token somewhere.

Usually you'd store it in your database linked to the user record there.

When you do an oauth requests for that user, you look up the token and use it again.